# Protobufs in Production - Isn't it heavy to include the compiler in production?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I haven't worked with Protobufs extensively, but have been asked to recently.

Installing the Protobuf compiler is pretty heavy on a local installation. I'm supposed to use `Protobuf` for serializing and deserializing messages on a server. `Flask` for simplicity.

Doesn't that mean on the server that I will also have to install this Protobuf Compiler?

Seems like it's quite heavy no? When all I want to do is serialize and deserialize messages?

> In passing, I heard that I don't need to include the compiler in production... But how would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, protobuf works by having a build-time step that parses a .proto schema file (usually "protoc"), which generates code in your chosen language. You then compile this with your app, and it is that generated code that does the actual work. The DSL parser/generator don't happen in your app, and you don't need to include them. The actual runtime code is ... just regular code.

Another option used by some protobuf tools is meta-programming, whereby the model (generated or hand-coded) contains enough information to *infer* how the serialization should happen, but no actual serialization code is generated. In this case, typically a strategy is emitted at runtime based on the model - usually the first time it is needed, then aggressively reused. This approach *does* need some runtime elements (the strategy emitter).

It is also possible to invoke the full DSL parser at runtime in various ways. In real terms, the parser isn't a huge piece of software, and as long as you aren't using it per-call it should usually be fine.